# PHP or wordpress renders escape characters as text

Tags: php, wordpress, text, escaping

I'm trying to help a friend with her website. I have full access to everything.
Her page renders escape characters as plain text. 
So if you look at wordpress source file wp-login.php line 173 - 175
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-login.php

```
$message = apply_filters( 'login_message', $message );
if ( !empty( $message ) )
    echo $message . "\n";
```

This is displayed on the login page as the text \n rather than a new line. 
The code from above is default wordpress code. It has not been altered in any way. I doubt there is a problem in the code. This has to be a server configuration error. php.ini looks pretty ordinary.  I have changed the wordpress config and commented out the encoding line UTF8, and db collation line with no effect. Also tried to manually specify db collation and page encoding.

Has any one seen this, and know a fix? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: could be your server's settings. Try echo "$message\n";
or just use <br /> instead: echo $message . '<br />';

Comment: I'm sure that will work, but like I said... this is default wordpress code. It works all over the net, except on this server.It should not be needed to alter out of the box code for my page to render correctly.

Comment: @BenFourie It might be helpful http://www.webmasters-central.com/blogging-and-autoblogging/wordpress-line-break-and-paragraph-problem-and-how-to-fix-it/

Answer (score 0):

Try “\n” instead of ‘\n’, no idea why, but this works

```
$message = apply_filters( 'login_message', $message );
if ( !empty( $message ) )
    echo $message . '\n';
```

There is function for line break

```
echo nl2br(" $message\n msg two lines");
```

when create html for the page it ignores and treating them as whitespace. If you want to use display a string formatted with "\n" you can use nl2br to convert it.

Comment: Did not work.Changed it from " to " without success.

Comment: are you doing this in which file??

Comment: I tried in wp_login.php
Allthough, I still believe it should not be needed to change wordpress files. Wordpress works well. There is some other issue that I do not understand, or cannot see yet.

Comment: your browser content-type because its not match with escap